# How can I do the equivalent to this mysql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My query is mysql is as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(nbdownloaded) FROM (
SELECT field1, field2, nbdownloaded
FROM mytable
Where .... 
 ) as reports
```

In rails I have the result of the subquery in variable.

Say for example I have:

```
my_reports = Reports.group("id").select("field1, field2, sum(field3) as nbdownloaded").where(...)")
```

And I want to have the sum of the field nbdownloaded.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it's quite easy in rails active record query,

```
Model.sum(:nbdownloaded).where(:column =>'your condition')
```

Comment: I updated my question for clarity. In the specific situation that I describe above what would you put in the condition. I tried several combinations but I cannot get it right.